# WatchOS open new interface from notification without launching app

Tags: swift, watchkit, unusernotificationcenter, watchos-4

What I'm hoping to do is this:

I want to have a notification on the watch that has custom actions. When one of the button actions is tapped I was hoping to have a new interface appear from the notification, but without launching the app. I want the user to then be able to adjust data with the crown and save that data.

Is there a way to present a new interface from the notification like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this currently. You could launch the app from the notification and detect that and then you could load a different view for the user. But other that that, it's not possible.